# FluentNHibernate cannot read connectionString from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

When I use FluentNHibernate, it is not able to read connection string from web.config. I am using ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework), Fluent NHibernate 2.0.3 and NHibernate 4.0.0.4000.

The commented way works fine to access the database, while the not commented one does not work.

```
        return Fluently.Configure()
            //.Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString("Server=localhost;Port=3307; Uid=root; Pwd=usbw;Database=hellonhibernate"))
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("TRP123456")))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PersonMap>())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionMap>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(CreateSchema)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TRP123456" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3307;uid=root;password=admin;database=hellonhibernate;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This is the error I got. Please help to see what is wrong. Thank you.

[image]

The structure of the project is as follow

[image]

Comment: Try to change: `Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("TRP123456")))` to `Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard    .ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TRP123456"].ConnectionString)))`

Comment: Hi Roma, thank you for your help. However, it seems does not work. I changed the code to the following but still get Null error. Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TR‌​P123456"].ConnectionString))

Comment: are you sure that you put connection string in right `config` file. Do you have only one application?

Comment: Hi Roma, I am sure I put the connectionString in web.config, where people usually put it. I attached an image to show my project structure, as well as the web.config structure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First check this question I think it might solve your problem [Access WebConfig in DotNet Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186445/access-web-config-settings-in-asp-net-core-app)

Another solution is to use appsettings.json file instead.

You can do that by adding a json file to your project. Same folder as project.json file.

In your startup.cs you just map your file to your app configuration as the following:

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration = null;
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true) // in my case the file name is appsettings.json
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build(); // returns IConfigurationRoot that can be used to access your settings later
    }
```

Now I am not sure about the static variable I created there it might not be the best way to go about it. But it gave me what I needed.

You can then use it to get your connectionstring like that :

```
Startup.Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectionString"]
```

Given that you have a ConnectionString key in your appsettings.json file.

```
{  
 "AppSettings": 
  {
   "ConnectionString": "" //type your connection string in here 
  }
}
```

**What is even better** is to add an AppSettings class like this:

```
 public class AppSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to map it as a service (Adding it to your middleware).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    { 
        //other services
        services.Configure<AppSettings> Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        //other services
    }
```

So you can inject it to your controllers:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    public _appsettings;
    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
       _appsettings = appSettings;
    }
 }
```

Finally you can now get your connection string by calling`_appsettings.ConnectionString` in your controller.