# Can someone confirm .NET Core can't run a legacy .NET class library that uses System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I have some legacy (.NET 4.6) code that uses ConfigurationManager to access AppSettings. I'm trying to use this class library in an Azure Function v3 and it fails with error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Before I spend the time to remove the dependency on System.Configuration it would be great to get confirmation (documented) that this specific scenario is not supported -- I can't find it anywhere.

Am I missing something simple for the interop or is it unsupported?

Comment: https://www.itnota.com/use-system-configuration-configurationmanager-dot-net-core/

Comment: @mxmissile that link is about using the ConfigurationManager when upgrading a legacy .NET app to .NET Core. My question is about using a third-party library that uses it. Moreover, before I posted this question I did try the suggested solution and any other I could find. Nothing worked.

Comment: So you just forgot to deploy it?  Good things might still happen if you give up on old bad practices, System.Configuration is high on that list.

Comment: No, and your comment is in line with what I'm seeing on other threads. This has nothing to do with deployment issues. The Azure Function is compiling in VS but at runtime when the code tries to execute the legacy class library it fails with the error mentioned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot add System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager to .NET core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473508/cannot-add-system-configuration-configurationmanager-to-net-core-application)

Comment: No, again this is about running a class library that uses .NET4.6 and uses the System.Configuration API within an Azure Function v3 (.Net CORE 3.1)

Answer (score 1):

Azure Function version 2 and above based on .Net core, you cannot use the existing .net Framework (4.6) library if they are not compatible.

When you will use existing .Net framework class library, you have to put your all configuration in .Json file. There is no concept of AppSetting in function. If you have only ConfigurationManager class issue, you can do below changes

**.Net Framework 4.6**

```
public string DatabaseId
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseId"];
        }
    }
```

**.Net Core 3.1 **

```
public string DatabaseId
    {
        get
        {
            return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DatabaseId");
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to touch your existing code, you can use Azure Function v1 with ConfigurationManager.

**Updated Answer**

ConfigurationManager is back, you can see this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20685) but I didn't found any documentation, how to use new configuration Manager. New [ConfigurationManager](https://www.fuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager) is .netstandard 2.0 compatible.

My looking [Source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e35a19cbd50cd5c159b8e5577f38f8be5838e227/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs#L34) I'm assuming it will read app setting from XML/JSON file but not sure how we can utilize this in .netstandard.

I have install `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` Nuget in my sample application (Console, Web and Function) but didn't get any values from JSON file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's the conclusion I came to as well. Is there any documentation that clearly calls this out? Where do I find a list of "compatible" APIs? Where does it say that System.Configuration is not supported in .NET Core?

Comment: Updated my answer with extra detail

Comment: Sorry I didn't fully follow that. Is your class library .NET4.6? Did it run correctly?

Comment: All projects in above screenshot from .net core 3.1 and I install System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager from nuget

Comment: Right, so that's not really addressing the question then because it's specifically about interop between .NET Framework and .NET Core