# Localized page names with ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

When create a Razor page, e.g. "Events.cshtml", one get its model name set to

```
@page
@model EventsModel
```

where the page's name in this case is "Events", and the URL would look like

```
http://example.com/Events
```

---

To be able to use page name's in Norwegian I added the following to the "Startup.cs"

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Events", "/hvaskjer");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Companies", "/bedrifter");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Contact", "/kontakt");
});
```

With this I can also use an URL like this and still serve the "Events" page

```
http://example.com/hvaskjer
```

---

I'm planning to support many more languages and wonder, is this the recommended way to setup localized page name's/route's?, or is there a more proper, *correct*  way to accomplish the same.

I mean, with the above sample, and having 15 pages in 10 languages it gets/feels messy using `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Page", "/side");` 150 times.

Comment: If it doesn’t sound like a “real” route but an alias for something else may be better off using either IIS url rewrite module or this middleware https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @numbtongue Thanks for your comment. As the app might run in other environment than e.g. IIS, I need to avoid such solution. Using middleware to do a rewrite feels less proper than what I have already, and am hoping that there will be a built-in option to solve this.

Comment: It would be nice if you can put them in a web.config where you could specify <location path=“konrakt”> (although may confuse future developer) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40220739/3254405

Comment: @numbtongue I wouldn't want to store hundreds of path tags in "web.config", they are stored and read from a db given the chosen language, and with that easy to change.

Comment: May be only create routes for domains like .com and .no and from there you’ll know which path to use..

Comment: @numbtongue Chosen language has nothing to do with which domain is being used.

Comment: Many large websites use language in query string such as /en/ or /fr/ (not sure if it’s any help) https://www.google.com/amp/s/gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/aspnet-core-simple-localization/amp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `IPageRouteModelConvention` interface. It provides access to the `PageRouteModel` where you can effectively add more templates for routes to match against for a particular page.

Here's a very simple proof of concept based on the following service and model:

```
public interface ILocalizationService
{
    List<LocalRoute> LocalRoutes();
}
public class LocalizationService : ILocalizationService
{
    public List<LocalRoute> LocalRoutes()
    {
        var routes = new List<LocalRoute>
        {
            new LocalRoute{Page = "/Pages/Contact.cshtml", Versions = new List<string>{"kontakt", "contacto", "contatto" } }
        };
        return routes;
    }
}

public class LocalRoute
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public List<string> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

All it does is provide the list of options for a particular page. The `IPageRouteModelConvention` implementation looks like this:

```
public class LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    private ILocalizationService _localizationService;

    public LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention(ILocalizationService localizationService)
    {
        _localizationService = localizationService;
    }

    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        var route = _localizationService.LocalRoutes().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Page == model.RelativePath);
        if (route != null)
        {
            foreach (var option in route.Versions)
            {
                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel()
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Template = option
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At Startup, Razor Pages build the routes for the application. The `Apply` method is executed for every navigable page that the framework finds. If the relative path of the current page matches one in your data, an additional template is added for each option.

You register the new convention in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention(new LocalizationService()));
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I were looking for. I did found the `IPageRouteModelConvention` though am too new to ASP.Net Core to figure out how-to :)

Comment: Just coincidentally, I have a draft of a blog article about this interface almost ready to go. I might include this use case as an additional example of its application.

Comment: I think you should, as I am sure this must be a very common issue on how to accomplish what I asked, and simple but very easy to understand samples like the one you gave, gives a very good understanding of how it works.

Comment: And I just figured out that if a page has a directive like `@page "{edit?}/{id?}"` one can/need to add that too for it all to work, e.g. `new LocalRoute{Page = "/Pages/Events.cshtml", Versions = new List<string>{"hvaskjer/{edit?}/{id?}" } }`

Comment: @MikeBrind how's it going with that blog post you mentioned? Is it published?

Comment: @PussInBoots I published it about 6 months ago: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/327/customising-routing-conventions-in-razor-pages

Comment: @MikeBrind How do you generate the links (<a asp-page="????">Link to localized version of contact page</a>) to the new localized routes?

Comment: @MikeBrind how would you add additional versions of a page, or new pages? Since the custom convention is executed once during app startup new pages or versions of a page would not be mapped to any route templates and I would need to restart my app every time I add new pages, e.g. when using a CMS.