# Get version when using IPageRouteModelConvention

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I sometime ago asked [how to add some kind of localized url's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317610/localized-page-names-with-asp-net-core-2-1), were `IPageRouteModelConvention` came into play in a, for me, perfect way.

With that I'm able to have routes in different languages/names.

---

If I use `www.domain.com/nyheter` (swedish) or `www.domain.com/sistenytt` (norwegian) I still only find, in `RouteData`, that the `News` route were used (`RouteData.Values["page"]`).

How do I get which version?

I know I can check/parse the `context.Request.Path` but am wondering if there is a built-in property that will give me it instead.

---

In `startup`

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention(new LocalizationService(appsettings.Routes)));
    });
```

---

`appsettings.Routes` is read from `appsettings.json`

```
"Routes": [
  {
    "Page": "/Pages/News.cshtml",
    "Versions": [ "nyheter", "sistenytt" ]
  },
  and so on....
]
```

---

The class

```
public class LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        private ILocalizationService _localizationService;

        public LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention(ILocalizationService localizationService)
        {
            _localizationService = localizationService;
        }

        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            var route = _localizationService.LocalRoutes().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Page == model.RelativePath);
            if (route != null)
            {
                foreach (var option in route.Versions)
                {
                    model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel()
                    {
                        AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                        {
                            Template = option
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve a `RouteData` value, you can specify a token within the template for a route. For example, the route `{version}` would add a `RouteData` value of `version` that would be taken from the URL's first segment. In your example, you don't specify a token for `version` and so there will be no `RouteData` value for it, as you've described.

The solution for your specific problem is two-part:

1. Instead of using specific values when creating new `SelectorModel`s, use a token as described above.
2. With this in place, you will now be able to access a `version` value from `RouteData`, but the new problem is that *any* value can be provided, whether or not it was specified in your configuration.

To solve the second problem, you can turn to `IActionConstraint`. Here's an implementation:

```
public class VersionConstraint : IActionConstraint
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> allowedValues;

    public VersionConstraint(IEnumerable<string> allowedValues)
    {
        this.allowedValues = allowedValues;
    }

    public int Order => 0;

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext ctx)
    {
        if (!ctx.RouteContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("version", out var routeVersion))
            return false;

        return allowedValues.Contains((string)routeVersion);
    }
}
```

`VersionConstraint` takes a list of allowed values (e.g. `nyheter`, `sistenytt`) and checks whether or not the `version` `RouteData` value matches. If it doesn't match, the "action" (it's really a page at this point) won't be a match and will end up with a 404.

With that implementation in place, you can update your implementation of `LocalizedPageRouteModelConvention`'s `Apply` to look like this:

```
var route = _localizationService.LocalRoutes().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Page == model.RelativePath);
if (route != null)
{
    model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
    {
        AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
        {
            Template = "{version}"
        },
        ActionConstraints =
        {
            new VersionConstraint(route.Versions)
        }
    });
}
```

This implementation adds a single new `SelectorModel` that's set up with a `Version` `RouteData` value and is constrained to only allow the values specified in configuration.